# NVIDIA Kepler bindless textures

Tags: cuda

In NVIDIA Kepler architecture, they have removed the necessity of binding textures. But I couldn't find simple example to illustrate this. Did anybody come across such example which can illustrate usage?

Comment: Why couldn't you find the example? It is available in the CUDA Toolkit 5.0 Samples. Take a look at the `bindLessTexture` sample in the `Graphics` section of CUDA Samples in CUDA Toolkit 5.0

Comment: @sgar91: Why couldn't you write that in an answer? :)

Comment: @RogerDahl... Well I thought it was just a minor question. Thanks for the suggestion. The answer will keep the question out of the **Unanswered** category.

Answer (score 5):

The CUDA samples that come along with CUDA Toolkit 5.0 contain samples for the Kepler architecture GPUs. The example usage of bindless textures is demonstrated in the **bindLessTexture** sample in the **Graphics** section of the CUDA 5.0 Samples.